# Syntax for subqueries in the FROM clause using multiple INNER JOIN's in MS Query

Tags: sql, excel, ms-query

I've been trying for a few days now (grrr) to pull data out of an ODBC-connected database using the manual SQL statement window in MS Query. I can see what it is I would like to do, but am getting hung up on the syntax (which I'm pretty sure is specific to MS Query).

The problem is this:

I have four tables: `waybill, waybill_item, rail_bl`, and `rail_bl_item`, which between them contain information on the weight processed through a shipping facility, with cargo either being routed onto trucks (waybill), or rail (rail). The `waybill` and `rail_bl` tables contain date data for truck and rail cargo, respectively; whereas the `waybill_item` and `rail_bl_item` contain data on the weight of those items.

I want a table that will return the total weights processed -- both rail and trucking -- for each day. I.E.

```
DATE | WEIGHT
date1, (truck_weight_for_date1+rail_weight_for_date1)
date2, (truck_weight_for_date2+rail_weight_for_date2)
date3, (truck_weight_for_date3+rail_weight_for_date3)
etc
```

By performing the query,

```
SELECT waybill.creation_date, sum(waybill_item.weight)
FROM waybill
INNER JOIN waybill_item
ON waybill.id = waybill_item.waybill_id
WHERE waybill.creation_date > '01/01/2012'
GROUP BY waybill.creation_date
UNION
SELECT rail_bl.creation_date, sum(rail_bl_item.total_weight)
FROM rail_bl
INNER JOIN rail_bl_item
ON rail_bl.id = rail_bl_item.rail_bl_id
WHERE rail_bl.creation_date > '01/01/2012'
GROUP BY rail_bl.creation_date
ORDER BY waybill.creation_date DESC
```

I am able to get a two-column result containing the total weights for trucks on a given day
and the total weights for rail on a given day *in separate records*, so my result looks like this:

```
DATE | WEIGHT
date1, truck_weight_for_date1
date1, rail_weight_for_date1
date2, truck_weight_for_date2
date2, rail_weight_for_date2
date3, truck_weight_for_date3
date3, rail_weight_for_date3
etc
```

The snag I'm hitting is that I can't get MS Query to accept using my above query as a
subquery, and subsequently summing the records for each date. Even trying to do a test with my query as a subquery doesn't work.

For example, trying

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT waybill.creation_date, sum(waybill_item.weight)
FROM waybill
INNER JOIN waybill_item
ON waybill.id = waybill_item.waybill_id
WHERE waybill.creation_date > '01/01/2012'
GROUP BY waybill.creation_date
UNION
SELECT rail_bl.creation_date, sum(rail_bl_item.total_weight)
FROM rail_bl
INNER JOIN rail_bl_item
ON rail_bl.id = rail_bl_item.rail_bl_id
WHERE rail_bl.creation_date > '01/01/2012'
GROUP BY rail_bl.creation_date
)
ORDER BY waybill.creation_date DESC
```

returns a "could not add the table '('" error. Other syntactical variants return similar errors.

Does anyone know how -- or even if -- MS Query is capable of performing subqueries like this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use this as a subquery, you need aliases in two places.  First, the columns need a name.  Second, the derived table needs a name:

```
select *
from (SELECT waybill.Creation_date, sum(waybil_item.weight) as Weight
      . . .
      union all
      . . .
     ) t
order by 1 desc
```

By the way, you want UNION ALL instead of UNION.  If you happened to have the same values on a given date, UNION would eliminate them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Gordon. The problem I'm running into now is simply trying to assign an alias, even on just one select with an INNER JOIN. If I try `SELECT waybill.creation_date, sum(waybill_item.weight) AS Total_Weight
FROM waybill
INNER JOIN waybill_item
ON waybill.id = waybill_item.waybill_id
WHERE waybill.creation_date > '01/01/2012'
GROUP BY waybill.creation_date` the header for the weight field remains blank, and going back to the SQL window shows that "AS Total_Weight" is gone. Any suggestions? I'm pretty new at this.